# Retrying requests with axios interceptors and forwarding responses back to frontend

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, axios, reverse-proxy

I have some technical questions regarding an assignment I did for a company in order to apply for a junior web developer position. The deadline was already in February but I could not finish the assignment in time. I would still want to finish it so here I am.

First, I am describing the purpose and function of the app. It is used to show product listings for the workers of an imaginary clothing warehouse. Currently, the user interface has a dropdown menu with three product categories: gloves, facemasks and beanies. Product list is updated by the selection in dropdown menu.

Second, data comes from two separate API's. Here is a quote from the API documentation:

```
GET /v2/products/:category – Return a listing of products in a given category.
GET /v2/availability/:manufacturer – Return a list of availability info.
The APIs are running at https://bad-api-assignment.reaktor.com/.
```

First API returns the product data, for example name, color, price and manufacturer. Product availability data (in stock, out of stock etc) comes from the second API.

Finally, the actual questions. I have a problem in handling erroneous responses coming from the API serving availability data. That API has a built-in intentional failure case where some of the responses have an empty array in random fashion (normally the array contains about 6000 objects). I am thinking to handle this error case in Node.js backend. The backend code shown below works only in ideal situations and does not handle the error case.

```
const express = require( 'express' )
const request = require( 'request' )
const app = express()
app.use( express.static( 'build' ))

/* Sets the needed CORS configuration to response header that is sent to the user's browser. */
app.use( ( req, res, next ) => {
    res.header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' )
    next()
} )

/* Forwards the frontend request to Reaktor Bad API server and the response back to frontend.
GET /v2/products/:category – Return a listing of products in a given category: gloves, facemasks or beanies.
GET /v2/availability/:manufacturer – Return a list of availability info.
The APIs are running at https://bad-api-assignment.reaktor.com/. */
app.get( '/api', ( req, res ) => {
    const category = req.query.category
    const manufacturer = req.query.manufacturer
    console.log( 'category query parameter: ', category )
    console.log( 'manufacturer query parameter: ', manufacturer )

    // Reaktor Bad API URL
    const baseUrl = 'https://bad-api-assignment.reaktor.com/v2'

    // craft full URL, make request to Bad API and forward response
    if ( category !== undefined ) {
        request( `${baseUrl}/products/${category}`, ( error, response ) => {
            console.error( 'category error:', error )
            console.log( 'category response & statusCode:', response && response.statusCode )
        } ).pipe( res )
    }
    else if ( manufacturer !== undefined ) {
        request( `${baseUrl}/availability/${manufacturer}`, ( error, response ) => {
            console.error( 'availability error:', error )
            console.log( 'availability response & statusCode:', response && response.statusCode )
        } ).pipe( res )
    }
    else {}
} )

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen( PORT, () => {
    console.log( `Server running on port ${PORT}` )
} )
```

As you see, I am using the express library in specifying routes. Two different frontend requests can come to the `/api` route in the form of query parameter: `category` or `manufacturer`. Based on the query parameter, appropriate request is sent to the API. Also, the now deprecated request library is used in the route. I would want to replace it with a newer alternative. request first requests data from external API and then passes it to frontend. To my understanding, this is called reverse proxy. In the frontend I am waiting for all availability data to arrive (using axios) and then build an array with product data combined with availability data. That array is then rendered as a product list shown in app user interface.

I have tried several ways to work around the issue and recently I learned about axios interceptors. Could they be used to retry requests that result in erroneous responses (empty arrays) and how? How about reverse proxy? Could it be done with axios and how? I have read the axios documentation but did not understand it. The motivation to use express and axios is because I am already somewhat familiar with them and request library is deprecated. Any help would be greatly appreciated. As I am still learning these things, responses that not only have the solution code but also tell its function would be the most beneficial for me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did a more simplistic one but not use Axios interceptors instead I just retry failed promises, it can be extended if you have more complex conditions, but the basic implementation is this.

```
/**
 * Sleeps for a given number of time
 * @param milliseconds milliseconds to sleep
 * @returns void promise
 */
export function sleep(milliseconds: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}

/**
 * Wraps a promise like to add retry capability.  This is resursive
 * @param fn promise to wrap
 * @param retries retries remaining
 * @param interval interval between retries
 * @returns promise
 */
export async function retryable<T>(
  fn: PromiseLike<T>,
  retries: number = 3,
  interval: number = 200
): Promise<T> {
  try {
    return await fn;
  } catch (error) {
    if (retries === 0) {
      throw error;
    }
    await sleep(interval);
    return await retryable(fn, retries - 1, interval);
  }
}
```

What I had instead in Axios was an interceptor that causes errors instead.  That way I can simulate failures on the client level rather than creating the scenario on the server side.

```
    if (failureRate > 0) {
      authenticatedClientRef.current.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
        if (Math.random() < failureRate) {
          throw Error('Intentional failure');
        } else {
          return req;
        }
      });
    }
```